# Bash: Batch rename nested directories or files with the same name

Tags: bash

I would like to rename the following directory:

From `1/2/3/2/2` to `1/2_re/3/2_re/2_re`.

Each directory has other contents too -for example file2stay.sh- which should stay untouched.

I tried the command:
`find ./ -exec bash -c 'mv 2 2_re' \;` but after it successfully renames the first directory the following error message appears:

`mv: cannot stat ‘2’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `find` with `sort -r` in a for loop using `process substitution`:

```
while read -r f; do
    mv "$f" "${f}_re"
done < <(find . -name '2' | sort -r)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell `find` to process the content of a folder before the folder itself using `-depth`:

```
find . -name "2" -type d -depth -execdir mv 2 2_re \;
```

`-execdir` executes the `mv` in the folder where the `./2` was found.